# Is htmx ready and usable with stale-while-revalidate pattern?

Tags: htmx, stale-while-revalidate

I just found out htmx and I would like to try it as soon as possible.

I also agree that javascript SPAs are a real fatigue.

I'm using SPAs mainly for two features:

1. I'm obsessed with perceived speed of rendering between pages transition. Especially with list > details workflows I'm using the stale-while-revalidate pattern a lot to increase the perceived speed of data fetching (using graphql normalized cache packages like Apollo and urql).
2. I'm really productive with code like frontend calculation only, example: the sum of invoices rows; I mean, list of something to calculate on frontend only without backend calls at all.

I searched a lot on Google (and on GitHub htmx's repo) for stale-while-revalidate pattern but nothing showed up.

I was thinking about using service worker for this but found nothing ready.

Can you help me find a way?